# How to check $H_0$ hypothesis using Pearson's criteria?

Tags: statistics, self-learning, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

How to check hypothesis by using Pearson's criteria ( $\chi^2$ test), that

$H_0:$ random variable $X$ is normally distributed

given that $k=7$ (count of intervals) and $\alpha=0.1 $ (significance level).

I do understand how you would have to approach problem where you would have to check simple hypothesis, like, for example,

$H_0:$ mean value of pages read by student of computer science faculty per day is greater than or equal 10, given that:

- $n=50$ (test group members)
- $\bar{x}=11.7$
- $s=1$

Then I would define

$H_a$ as: mean value of pages read by student of computer science faculty per day is less than 10.

and calculate $$z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}}$$
and look up P-Value from normal curve areas table. Then comparing P-value against $\alpha$ would determine that $H_a$ would be rejected and therefore $H_0$ would be approved.

But how do I approach my problem?

$$H_0: X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
$$H_a: X\nsim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$